# IIS7 URL Rewrite root files only

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

This question was asked 4 years ago yet no answers on them.

The situation is, to rewrite root/xyz to root/index.php?code=xyz without affecting any other files and subdirectories.

I have already did this rewrite using the following

```
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>

<rule name="Rewrite User Links to Get">
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)" /> 
<action type="Rewrite" url="?code={ToLower:{R:1}}" />
</rule> 

</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

But with this code, other files in the root and sub directories ceases to function. What match string or expression should I use to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question here [IIS 7.0 URL Rewrite Module - Root URL doesn't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119936/iis-7-0-url-rewrite-module-root-url-doesnt-display?rq=1)

```
<match url="^(?:([^/.]+))?$" />
```

This fixed the problem.